How do I search for the index of an int[2] in a list?
So, I'm poking around at being able to search for the index of an int[2] in a list but I haven't had much luck.
Below is the code I've been playing with:
var coordinates = new List<int[]>();
coordinates.Add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
coordinates.Add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
coordinates.Add(new int[] { 5, 6 });

//foreach (int[] array in coordinates)
//{
//    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
//}

coordinates.AddRange(new int[3][] { [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12] });
foreach (int[] array in coordinates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
}

//var index = coordinates.IndexOf([3,4]);
var index = coordinates.IndexOf(new int[] { 3, 4 });
Console.WriteLine(index);

Both the above IndexOf lines have returned a value of -1 so I assume my syntax is wrong (or I'm using the wrong tools, which is also possible).  Any suggestions?

You're trying to find the index of a new array, not the one in the list. If you assign your array to a variable it will find it.

IndexOf method will not work directly on array elements since it uses the Equals method for arrays. This checks for reference equality rather than content equality. Therefore, you need to compare the contents of the arrays manually.
So, instead of using int array I would prefer values represented as strings which makes easy to find the index of the value.
using System.Collections.Generic;

var coordinates = new List<string>();
coordinates.Add("1,2");
coordinates.Add("3,4");
coordinates.Add("5,6");
coordinates.Add("7,8");
coordinates.Add("9,10");
coordinates.Add("11,12");

foreach (string item in coordinates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

var _valueToSearch = "7,8";
var index = coordinates.IndexOf(_valueToSearch);
Console.WriteLine(index);

Also, you may try to implement your own search logic some thing like this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var coordinates = new List<int[]>();
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 5, 6 });
        coordinates.AddRange(new int[3][] { new int[] { 7, 8 }, new int[] { 9, 10 }, new int[] { 11, 12 } });

        foreach (int[] array in coordinates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
        }

        var _valueToSearch = new int[] { 3, 4 };

        int index = FindIndex(coordinates, _valueToSearch);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }

    static int FindIndex(List<int[]> list, int[] valueToSearch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (AreArraysEqual(list[i], valueToSearch))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1; // Not found
    }

    static bool AreArraysEqual(int[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i] != array2[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}


Ah, I think I follow.  So it's not that it CAN'T be done, just the approach is exponentially more complicated than just handling it as a string.  That's good to know!  Thanks for the advice, definitely pointed me a better direction!

Arrays in C# are reference types. They are equal to each other when the underlying object is the same.
In your code, you use new keyword when searching for matching array, which creates new underlying array object, just with the same elements, but it is different object underneath.
To correctly find index of an array with desired items you can first find the desired array (by using FirstOrDefault and SequenceEqual - mind that items must be in order for that to work) and then look for its index, like below:
var matchingArray = coordinates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 3, 4 }));
var index = coordinates.IndexOf(matchingArray);

If you use C# 12, you can use collection expression:
x.SequenceEqual([3, 4])


Pulling the new int[] { .. into a captured variable would avoid lots of allocations. Or at least use the new collection expression [ 3, 4 ] so a stackalloc could be used under the hood.

Arrays in C# are equal if they are the same array, not if they have the same content. You'll want to scan the list with a loop or using LINQ methods like list.First(x => x.SequenceEqual(needle))

You're trying to find the index of a new array, not the one in the list. If you assign your array to a variable it will find it.
var yourArray = new int[] { 3, 4 };
coordinates.Add(yourArray);

//...

var index = coordinates.IndexOf(yourArray); //1


I guess I don't understand what the difference in the approaches are.  In both these examples, I expect it to have to same entry.  Are these not the same?  What am I missing?
'
coordinates.Add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
'
'
var yourArray = new int[] { 3, 4 };
coordinates.Add(yourArray);
'
To my eyes, the look exactly the same but they're being processed differently

@JB - They reference different objects (arrays are reference types). You created a new one, which may resemble the original, but is not the same one.

For example, imagine you made a PB&J sandwich (sorry, I'm hungry), but then you decided to make a second one on with the exact same ingredients, in the same way. Now you have 2 identical sandwiches. That's (essentially) what's happening here.

Ok, that makes sense.  In my head, one has a unique key, the other doesn't, or something to that effect.  How do I resolve this with my original intent, to be able to identify that it is A PB&J sandwich, not a specific one?  I guess that's my question.

@JB - If you are able to assign the object to a variable, that's generally more efficient. If you can't for some reason or just need to perform a search, something like one of the answers that uses SequenceEqual might be what you need.

That makes sense.  Thanks so much for all your help!  I appreciate it!

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var coordinates = new List<int[]>();
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 3, 4 });
        coordinates.Add(new int[] { 5, 6 });

        coordinates.AddRange(new int[3][] 
        {
            new int[] { 7, 8 }, 
            new int[] { 9, 10 }, 
            new int[] { 11, 12 } 
        });

        foreach (int[] array in coordinates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
         }

        var searchArray = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        var index = coordinates.FindIndex(arr => arr[0] == searchArray[0] 
&& arr[1] == searchArray[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(index); // This should now return the correct 
index.
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Because your list is called coordinates, I assume all arrays of the list will always have 2 elements. Because your arrays are not just some amount of numbers, but have an actual meaning, it is recommended to create a class:
public class Coordinate
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
}

This is a great improvement, because coordinates[0].X or coordinates[0].Y will tell you more what is going on in your code than coordinates[0][0] or coordinates[0][1]. But you will still have problems finding your coordinate with IndexOf method as pointed out in the other answers, because your coordinate is a reference type. Hence it is wise to implement IEquatable<Coordinate> and create your own comparision:
public class Coordinate : IEquatable<Coordinate>
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }

   public bool Equals(Coordinate other)
   {
       return this.X == other?.X && this.Y == other?.Y;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object other)
   {
       return other is Coordinate coordinate && Equals(coordinate);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
        return (X,Y).GetHashCode();
   }
   
   public  static bool operator ==(Coordinate left, Coordinate right)
   {
        if(left is null)
        {
            return right is null;
        }
        return left.Equals(right);
   }
   
   public  static bool operator !=(Coordinate left, Coordinate right)
   {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}

If you override Equals, you also have to override GetHashCode, that objects that are equal also have the same hash code. I just calculated the hashcode of a value tuple containing the X and the Y property. For convenience, I also overloaded the == and != operator. This means, you will be able to do stuff like if(coord1 == coord2) { }. With the class, your code will become:
var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
coordinates.Add(new Coordinate { X = 1, Y = 2 });
coordinates.Add(new Coordinate { X = 3, Y = 4 });
coordinates.Add(new Coordinate { X = 5, Y = 6 });
int index = coordinates.IndexOf(new Coordinate {X = 3, Y = 4});

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZE7BLr
